# Why are RVM related commands failing to run within a shell script ... but behave as expected direct in terminal

Tags: shell, rvm

```
ubuntu@ip-10-114-202-137:~$ sudo ./ghgvc.sh 
./ghgvc.sh: 4: ./ghgvc.sh: rvmsudo: not found
./ghgvc.sh: 5: ./ghgvc.sh: rvm: not found
./ghgvc.sh: 6: ./ghgvc.sh: rvm: not found
./ghgvc.sh: 8: ./ghgvc.sh: source: not found
 SSH back in to re-source RVM 
ubuntu@ip-10-114-202-137:~$ which rvmsudo
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvmsudo
```

The above error comes from this script:

```
if [ "$RVM_RELOADED" ]; then
  echo "RVM was reloaded... proceeding"
else
  rvmsudo rvm get head
  rvm group add rvm $USER
  rvm reload
  echo "export rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1" > ~/.rvmrc  #auto-trust .rvmrc flags  
  source ~/.rvmrc

  export RVM_RELOADED="1"
  echo " SSH back in to re-source RVM "
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You call your script with `sudo` this removes whole environment context, to accomplish what you try to do you need to `source` the script instead:

```
source ghgvc.sh
```